# Lambdas not invoked during a certain period of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

here is my problem:

I have about 1400 lambdas in an AWS account and I would like to know how to measure the lambdas that haven't been invoked during the last X days range. I've tried to do it using cloudwatch but had no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way for you to accomplish this would likely be with [GitHub: Enumerate Lambda functions across all regions with useful metadata](https://github.com/epsagon/list-lambdas). It returns the last invocation time to detect "dead Lambdas".

There is also this AWS blog post that shows an example: [Automating the discovery of unused AWS Lambda functions | AWS Cloud Operations & Migrations Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/automating-the-discovery-of-unused-aws-lambda-functions/)